# css image background does not resize properly in browser

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html><head>
  <link href="css/testphoto2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="Smiley face" width="420" height="420">  

  <header class="section" >
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

and this css:

```
body {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #111;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\;
}
.section {
   display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 200px 0;   
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I want to have the kitty scale properly as the browser is resized. In the first image, the kitty reaches its native maximum and stays there, regardless of further browser enlargement. The second kitty fills the browser width but only stretches horizontally once the browser exceeds its native width. I would like the kitty to scale in both dimensions as the browser window grows. If I remove the 'padding' property from the css, the kitty disappears.

Comment: Try to add a max-height property in your .section

Answer (score 0):

Change in your CSS for "section" class as:

```
.section {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px; /* height should have to provide */
 background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center scroll;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Height should have to provide.

Comment: that did not fix any thing. however the following code fixed the first kitty

Comment: img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: inherit !important;
    height: inherit !important;
}

Comment: @aquagremlin your code did not fullfill the solution actually.

Comment: Consider your answer @aquagremlin. You added code in section class also. Now its perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make height:100% for HTML, body and section. Remove padding from section

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #111;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
.section {
   display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;       
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

check this out

```
https://jsfiddle.net/160cL4xo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width & height of html & body to 100%. Remove Padding from section.

```
html,body{ 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Working Demo: [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/p8yf6995/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for getting the background image to scale properly. The kitty gets cropped in some way or another with scaling. The effect I want to achieve is provided by this css:

```
html, body {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: inherit !important;
    height: inherit !important;
}
```

but I do not know how to achieve it for a background image. Notice how the entire kitty fills the frame proportionately and is never cropped with resizing.

EDIT: This fixes the background image:

.section {
   display: inline-table;
    padding: 80% 0;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center ;
    background-size: cover;
    width: inherit !important;
    height: inherit !important;

}

Don't ask me why 80% is needed. But the background kitty now fills the frame and scales just like the html kitty.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ox2dy086/
```

Answer (score -1):

Change in your CSS for "section" class as:

```
.section {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px; /* height should have to provide */
 background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center scroll;
 background-size: cover;
}
```